# TLP problem with headphone input jack

Tags: 16.04, headphones, tlp

Since i installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop i've been trying to have more battery life(I can only use it for around 3 hours without plugging it). 
I found TLP, and read some good opinions about it, so I installed it, and its ok, but when I connect headphones to the laptop through the headphone jack input, the laptop instantly turns off.

Comment: Did you uninstall TLP to be sure it causes the issue? Also refer  to [TLP Troubleshooting](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-troubleshooting.html).

Comment: Yes, without having TLP installed there is no issue whith the headphone jack input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a kernel issue where the driver with powersave enabled goes berserk and turns the machine off.

I suggest to isolate the offending device / driver as described in [TLP Troubleshooting](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-troubleshooting.html).